# What is this colour scheme element?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, color-scheme

I'm using VS2010 with ReSharper and "Son Of Obsidian" theme and have the following frustrating highlighting issue in String.Format sections.

Selecting a method (or any) parameter gives the grey background - see `string bString` in picture. But the highlighting inside the String.Format string is different, and unreadable.

In "Tools > Options > Font and Colors" I've tried: "Selected Text", "Inactive Selected Text" and "Highlighted Reference" both in vain.

So please:

a) What do I need to change

b) Is there a decent way of finding it out (I've tried doing a screen grab for the Hex color code and searching for that in the style XML, but that doesn't work)

[image: Irritating highlighting issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an age of trying this out on my home PC I've discovered the element in question is `ReSharper Matched Format String Item`

[image: ReSharper Matched Format String Item]

There should really be an easier way of finding this stuff out

Answer (score 1):

It appears your cursor is in an Intellisense Code Snippet field.

Could it be Code Snippet Field?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, found it in the end `ReSharper Matched Format String Item`

Answer (score 0):

Paddy's reply pointed me in the correct direction, but my issue was slightly different. I'm going to post my solution here in the hope that it might help others.

I'm using VS2013 and Resharper 8. My issue was that Resharper had not been able to import it's own Font and Colour settings on installation. For me, the Resharper options shown in Paddy's image were not visible. This is a known issue with Resharper installation and the solution is as follows:

1) Close all Visual Studio instances

2) Open C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {VS version}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\extensions.configurationchanged file

3) Type anything there

4) Save the file

5) Open VS and check Fonts and Colors in Tools | Options | Environment

([source](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/26859128-ReSharper-Fonts-Colors-settings-do-not-appear-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation))

For me, as soon as I reopened VS, Resharper had been able to import its own settings and the highlighting issue was already fixed without needing any further action from me.

Now, when trying to edit the extensions.configurationchanged file, I also ran in to an "Access is Denied" error message (I'm running Windows 7 as an admin). To overcome this I had to open Notepad as an administrator (Start > right click notepad > Run as administrator) and then use File > Open to open the extensions.configurationchanged file.

I hope this helps people in the future!